# Using performAjaxValidation inside a widget (Yii)

Tags: ajax, validation, yii, widget

I've created a widget with a CActiveForm in it. Everything works ok, but now i want to enable ajax validation for it.

The problem is that the output of my ajax validation is containing, besides the validation JSON string, all (well a part of it, since `Yii::app()->end()` stops the rest) of my html as well. Not weird, because i'm using it within a widget and the validation request is done to the controller/action where i've placed this widget on.

Is there some way to prevent outputting all the html, so a valid JSON string is returned?

I've already tried to set the `validationUrl` in the CActiveForm to another controller/action, but the problem is that i have to send the model with it and this model is determined in my widget and not on the validationUrl.

**Widget:**

```
    public function run()
    {

        $model = new User;
        $model->scenario = 'create';

        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {

            $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];

            if ($model->save()) {



            }

        }

        $this->render('register-form', array(
            'model' => $model
        ));

    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param User $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']))
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

**Output of performAjaxValidation() (the ajax call):**

```
.. more html here ..
<section class="box">

    <h1>Register form simple</h1>

    {"UserPartialSignup_email":["Email is geen geldig emailadres."]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it this way:

I've created an AJAX controller where the validation is done:

**AjaxController:**

```
    /**
     * Validates a model.
     *
     * Validates a model, POST containing the data. This method is usually used for widget based forms.
     *
     * @param $m model name which have to be validated
     * @param $s scenario for this model, optional.
     * @return string JSON containing the validation data
     */

     public function actionValidate($m, $s = null)
     {

        if ($this->checkValidationData($m, $s) && isset($_POST['ajax']))
        {
            $model = new $m;
            $model->scenario = $s;

            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();


        } else {

            throw new CHttpException(500, 'No valid validation combination used');

        }

     }
```

You can give the model name and a scenario as GET parameters with it, i'm checking if this combination is allowed by the `checkValidationData()` method.

In the view of my widget where the CActiveForm is placed, i've added the validationUrl, referring to ajax/validate:

**widgets/views/registerform.php:**

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'signup-form-advanced',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validationUrl' => array('ajax/validate', 'm' => get_class($model), 's' => 'create')
    )
    //'enableClientValidation'=>true,
)); ?>
```